# Workaround for xp_cmdshell in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, xp-cmdshell

Stored procedure in on-premises SQL Server is used to call another app through 'xp_cmdshell'. 
Now I am trying to do the same on Azure SQL Database. Of course 'xp_cmdshell' is not supported there, so I need workaround.

I was thinking of using Azure Functions as a bridge between  Azure SQL Database and app on VM.

1. Is it possible to call Azure Function from Azure SQL Database using
   stored procedure?
2. Is it possible to call app on Azure VM from Azure
   Function?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not at the moment. The workaround is to create a Timer-based Azure Function that polls the data every "x" minutes or seconds.
2. As long the app on Azure VM expose an HTTP endpoint, and you configure the network and the firewall correctly, yes.

Comment: 1. Thanks for solution but I already have implicit periodic execution. What I need is possibility to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use [Azure Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) to [run tasks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-run-tasks-on-azure-virtual-machines-without-opening-ports/) on the VM then using a pipeline in [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) you can invoke the runbook using a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks)